# Overloaded Methods with User Input (ReadLine())

Tags: c#, user-input, overloading

I am working through learning C# myself (not homework) and am confused about method overloading when there is user input.

I am doing an exercise that allows the user to input a bid amount for an item.  I need to include 3 overloaded methods (int, double, string). *(The exercise says to use double not decimal.)*

I know how to write the overloaded methods, my confusion comes with the user input.  If I accept the input (ReadLine) as a string, it chooses the string method, if I accept the input as a int, the int method is called.  How do I deal with this?  Do I use tryParse?  How can I do this with 3 possible input methods (int, double, string)?

Also, to add a frustrating twist, for the string to be accepted it must be numeric and preceded with '$' sign or numeric followed by "dollars".  I am hoping that I completed that correctly in the code below.  Wasn't sure how to trim by string, so I had to do it by character...

Hoping for a basic/simple explanation, as I haven't learned anything too fancy yet.

Thank you!

```
namespace Auction
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        string entryString;
        //int entryInt;  // do I need this?
        //int entryDouble;  // do I need this?
        double bidNum;

        const double MIN = 10.00;
        Console.WriteLine("\t** WELCOME TO THE AUCTION! **\n");

        Console.Write("Please enter a bid for the item:  ");
        entryString = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
        double.TryParse(entryString, out bidNum);  // this turns it into a double...

        BidMethod(bidNum, MIN);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void BidMethod(int bid, double MIN)
    {  // OVERLOADED - ACCEPTS BID AS AN INT
        Console.WriteLine("Bid is an int.");
        Console.WriteLine("Your bid is: {0:C}", bid);
        if (bid >= MIN)
            Console.WriteLine("Your bid is over the minimum {0} bid amount.", MIN);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Your bid is not over the minimum {0} bid amount.", MIN);
    }

    private static void BidMethod(double bid, double MIN)
    {  // OVERLOADED - ACCEPTS BID AS A DOUBLE

        Console.WriteLine("Bid is a double.");
        Console.WriteLine("Your bid is: {0:C}", bid);
        if (bid >= MIN)
            Console.WriteLine("Your bid is over the minimum {0} bid amount.", MIN);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Your bid is not over the minimum {0} bid amount.", MIN);
    }

    private static void BidMethod(string bid, double MIN)
    {  // OVERLOADED - ACCEPTS BID AS A STRING

        string amount;
        int amountInt;

        if (bid.StartsWith("$")) 
            amount = (bid as string).Trim('$');  // Remove the $
        if (bid.EndsWith("dollar"))
            amount = bid.TrimEnd(' ', 'd', 'o', 'l', 'l', 'a', 'r', 's');
        else
            amount = bid;

        Int32.TryParse(amount, out amountInt);  // Convert to Int
        Console.WriteLine("Bid is a string.");

        Console.WriteLine("Your bid is: {0:C}", bid);
        if (amountInt >= MIN)
            Console.WriteLine("Your bid is over the minimum {0} bid amount.", MIN);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Your bid is not over the minimum {0} bid amount.", MIN);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: Thanks, new to the site...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are looking to support various ways of entering a dollar amount, then I would suggest your idea of using `TryParse` could work:

- First use `int.TryParse` - as `int` is most restrictive (doesn't
  allow decimal point etc)
- Second use `double.TryParse`
- Finally, if neither of those work, keep as a string.

Comment: The formatting of the double may cause problems as well, since he said it has characters around it. As a sidenote, currency should be stored as a `decimal` rather than a `double`.

Comment: that part is handled in the string overload as far as I can see. agree about decimal in a real worlds example

Comment: Do I need to use an if statement with this?  It just keeps calling all of the methods or saying that it is an int when it is a double - I only want to call one method based on the user's input...  Please help, super frustrated with this one...

Answer (score 0):

I think that replacing `int` and `double` versions with a `decimal` version would be more appropriate since `decimal` is more convenient for storing money values (search SO for more details).

So, read input, search for a dollar sign, if there is none, use `decimal.TryParse()` and a `decimal` overload else use the `string` overload.

As there is no difference in processing a number whether it contains a dollar sign or not, I would do the following.

```
...
string entryString = Console.ReadLine();
BidMethod(entryString, 10.00m); // m stands for decimal, d for double
...

private static void BidMethod(string bid, decimal min)
{   
    decimal number;
    if (decimal.TryParse(bid.Replace("$", ""), out number))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your bid is: {0:C}", bid);
        if (number >= min)
            Console.WriteLine("Your bid is over the minimum {0} bid amount.", min);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Your bid is not over the minimum {0} bid amount.", min);   
    }
}
```

Comment: In that case I wouldn't do that excercise because it teaches you bad habits of using double for money. Do this somewhere where values actually matter and you will desperately search where is the problem with 1+1 not being 2 (although with different values).

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding and your comments:
Hence you need (or the exercise requests) to accept `int`, `double` or `string` only.

I think you would need to first check if the input value containing **$** or not, if so then you can call the string function.

Then you will check the value as `int` using `Int32.TryParse` if succeeded then call the int function

Last step is by checking the value as `double` by using `Double.TryParse`

`Double`'s length is way more than `int`, that's why you should be checking `int` first

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
namespace Auction
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string entryString;
            decimal bidNum;
            const decimal MIN = 10.00m;

            Console.Write("Please enter a bid for the item:  ");
            entryString = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
            decimal.TryParse(entryString, out bidNum);  // this turns it into a double...

            BidMethod(bidNum, MIN);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: code-only answers are discouraged, and for a reason: How does the code presented answer *How do I deal with alternative input formats?*